# how do I get "ALL" input option to include all dates in flexdashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have some input selections in my flexdashboard sidebar that allows you to filter the dashboard data. First you choose a name and then you get a list of dates to choose from available under that name. this is the code below:

**## Sidebar {.sidebar}**

```
selectInput(inputId = "player_name", label = "Select Player Name", choices = unique(VALD$`Player Name`))
# Get corresponding Dates for Picked Name
single_athlete_dates <- reactive({
  VALD %>%
    filter(`Player Name` == input$player_name)
})
```

```
renderUI({selectInput(inputId = "date", label = "Select Test Date", choices = unique(single_athlete_dates()$Date))})
```

Is there a way to select "ALL" dates just like in Power BI instead of having to choose to show data from a single date? some data will not show under a certain date because the data was not collected that day, so by choosing "ALL" I want to be able to get the most recent data from all dates available.